# How to skip formatting SD Card?

Tags: external-sd

My android phone keeps saying my fully working SD Card is damaged and I have only the choice to format.
I tested it on every smartphone I have, the same error.
But when I put this SD Card in my laptop or Windows phone smartphone:
 - the SD card works fine;
 - can listen to the music just fine;
 - no problem when watching a movie from it;
 - working just one more time on a single Android phone, then the error again.
I tested it with chkdsk, no problem.

What can I do? How can I skip the formatting?

Comment: Which is its filesystem?

Comment: FAT32 filesystem

Comment: Have you tried copying off the data to your PC, inserting the card in the phone and formatting it, then putting the card back in your PC and copying the data back? This is likely one of those issues where there is an inconsistency between the implementation of FAT32 in Windows and Android, this action will usually correct it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best answer here is by @Android_Helper. I would recommend backing up the data before doing what I'm about to suggest. I have been able to skip formatting by repeatedly removing and inserting the SD card until it detects it. This method does not always worK but sometimes it would work for me the 10th time or so.

Comment: Thats another alternative..for the solution

Comment: It's what I'd do in a desperate/lazy situation. Not really recommended, but I thought I'd leave it here as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Try to backup your data to your laptop then Format it to your Android smartphone then restore your backup data.

Comment: I have done that, the same after smartphone reboot. I think I will stick with opening it on my laptop just to save some time and not copying/backing up the huge amount of movies and music all the time.